# Can not query table with type double precision[] from PostGis with geotools

Tags: java, postgresql, geotools

- Postgres 9
- Postgis
- GeoTools 12.2

In Java backend I try to make a query via geotools. It works fine until I try to make a query with attibute of type "double precision[]".

First geotools log a Warning:

```
org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource buildFeatureType
WARNING: Could not find mapping for '<my column name>', ignoring the column and setting the feature type read only
```

And then somewhere deep down, more or less around PostGISDialect level, it throws a NullPointerException. I tried to debug whole thing and I found that for JDBCFeatureSource "double precision[]" is "_float8" (typeName) and sqlType is "2003" (which is ARRAY in java.sql.Types). And JDBFeatureSource can not find binding neither for _float8 nor for SQL ARRAY type.
I tried to find some information if I can extend geotools with my own data type but I failed. Does anyone has any idea how can I use "double precision[]" type with geotools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao,
simply put you cannot right now.

Longer explanation, I don't think there is a mapper in GeoTools PostGISDialect for that type of data. You might want to provide a patch for it, it should not be too hard.

Simone.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I might try to write a patch. I would appreciate if you could give me some hint where could I start to watch in code. Is PostGISDialect class a good starting point?

Comment: I think so.
I would then bring the discussion to the ML to get some additional info.

Simone.